# WPF Application Using MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Question : Create a simple WPF application using MVVM.Application should display a button for each day os the current year and Display a date.Upon clicking on the buttons they should display a message with name of the day of week.

Solution:I have created this application and run successfully but it's code wise doesn't look excellent.

**Model Code:**

```
public class DateDataModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    DateTime FirstDate= new DateTime( DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, 1);

    public string Now
    {
        get { return FirstDate.ToShortDateString(); }
        set
        {
            Now = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Now");

        }
    }
    public string Now1
    {
        get { return FirstDate.AddDays(1).ToShortDateString(); }
        set
        {
            Now1 = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Now1");

        }
    }
    public string Now2
    {
        get { return FirstDate.AddDays(1).ToShortDateString(); }
        set
        {
            Now2 = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Now2");

        }
    }
    public string Now3
    {
        get { return FirstDate.AddDays(3).ToShortDateString(); }
        set
        {
            Now5 = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Now3");

        }
    }
    public string Now4
    {
        get { return FirstDate.AddDays(4).ToShortDateString(); }
        set
        {
            Now4 = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Now4");

        }
    }
    public string Now5
    {
        get { return FirstDate.AddDays(5).ToShortDateString(); }
        set
        {
            Now5 = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Now5");

        }
    }
    public string Now6
    {
        get { return FirstDate.AddDays(6).ToShortDateString(); }
        set
        {
            Now6 = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Now6");

        }
    }
    public string Now7
    {
        get { return FirstDate.AddDays(7).ToShortDateString(); }
        set
        {
            Now7 = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Now7");

        }
    }
    public string Now8
    {
        get { return FirstDate.AddDays(8).ToShortDateString(); }
        set
        {
            Now1 = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Now8");

        }
    }
    public string Now9
    {
        get { return FirstDate.AddDays(9).ToShortDateString(); }
        set
        {
            Now1 = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Now9");

        }
    }
    public string Now10
    {
        get { return FirstDate.AddDays(10).ToShortDateString(); }
        set
        {
            Now3 = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Now10");

        }
    }
    public string Now11
    {
        get { return FirstDate.AddDays(11).ToShortDateString(); }
        set
        {
            Now1 = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Now11");

        }
    }
    public string Now12
    {
        get { return FirstDate.AddDays(12).ToShortDateString(); }
        set
        {
            Now1 = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Now112");

        }
    }
    public string Now13
    {
        get { return FirstDate.AddDays(13).ToShortDateString(); }
        set
        {
            Now1 = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Now13");

        }
    }
    public string Now14
    {
        get { return FirstDate.AddDays(14).ToShortDateString(); }
        set
        {
            Now1 = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Now14");

        }
    }

    public string Now15
    {
        get { return FirstDate.AddDays(15).ToShortDateString(); }
        set
        {
            Now15 = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Now15");

        }
    }
    public string Now16
    {
        get { return FirstDate.AddDays(16).ToShortDateString(); }
        set
        {
            Now16 = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Now16");

        }
    }
    public string Now17
    {
        get { return FirstDate.AddDays(17).ToShortDateString(); }
        set
        {
            Now17 = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Now17");

        }
    }
    public string Now18
    {
        get { return FirstDate.AddDays(18).ToShortDateString(); }
        set
        {
            Now18 = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Now18");

        }
    }
    public string Now19
    {
        get { return FirstDate.AddDays(19).ToShortDateString(); }
        set
        {
            Now19 = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Now19");

        }
    }
    public string Now20
    {
        get { return FirstDate.AddDays(20).ToShortDateString(); }
        set
        {
            Now20= value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Now20");

        }
    }
    public string Now21
    {
        get { return FirstDate.AddDays(21).ToShortDateString(); }
        set
        {
            Now21 = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Now21");

        }
    }
    public string Now22
    {
        get { return FirstDate.AddDays(22).ToShortDateString(); }
        set
        {
            Now22 = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Now22");

        }
    }
    public string Now23
    {
        get { return FirstDate.AddDays(23).ToShortDateString(); }
        set
        {
            Now23 = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Now23");

        }
    }
    public string Now24
    {
        get { return FirstDate.AddDays(24).ToShortDateString(); }
        set
        {
            Now24 = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Now24");

        }
    }
    public string Now25
    {
        get { return FirstDate.AddDays(25).ToShortDateString(); }
        set
        {
            Now25 = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Now25");

        }
    }
    public string Now26
    {
        get { return FirstDate.AddDays(26).ToShortDateString(); }
        set
        {
            Now26 = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Now26");

        }
    }
    public string Now27
    {
        get { return FirstDate.AddDays(27).ToShortDateString(); }
        set
        {
            Now27 = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Now27");

        }
    }
    public string Now28
    {
        get { return FirstDate.AddDays(28).ToShortDateString(); }
        set
        {
            Now28 = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Now28");

        }
    }
    public string Now29
    {
        get { return FirstDate.AddDays(29).ToShortDateString(); }
        set
        {
            Now29 = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Now29");

        }
    }
    public string Now30
    {
        get { return FirstDate.AddDays(30).ToShortDateString(); }
        set
        {
            Now30 = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Now30");

        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
    }


}
```

}

**View Model Code:**

```
public class ButtonViewModel
{
    private DateDataModel _dateModel;

    public ButtonViewModel()
    {
        _dateModel = new DateDataModel();

    }

    public DateDataModel Dates
    {
        get { return _dateModel; }
        set { _dateModel = value; }
    }

    private ICommand mUpdater;
    public ICommand UpdateCommand
    {
        get
        {
            if (mUpdater == null)
                mUpdater = new DateUpdater(this);
            return mUpdater;
        }
        set
        {
            mUpdater = value;
        }
    }

    private class DateUpdater : ICommand
    {
        #region ICommand Members
        ButtonViewModel _obj;
        public DateUpdater(ButtonViewModel obj)
        {
            _obj = obj;
        }



        public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
        {
            return true;
        }

        public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

        public void Execute(object parameter)
        {
            if (parameter == null) return;

            Button clickedbutton = parameter as Button;
            DateTime dt = DateTime.MinValue;
            switch (clickedbutton.Name.ToString())
            {
                case "btnUpdate":
                    dt = Convert.ToDateTime(_obj.Dates.Now.ToString());
                    break;
                case "btnUpdate1":
                    dt = Convert.ToDateTime(_obj.Dates.Now1.ToString());
                    break;
                case "btnUpdate2":
                    dt = Convert.ToDateTime(_obj.Dates.Now2.ToString());
                    break;
                case "btnUpdate3":
                    dt = Convert.ToDateTime(_obj.Dates.Now3.ToString());
                    break;
                case "btnUpdate4":
                    dt = Convert.ToDateTime(_obj.Dates.Now4.ToString());
                    break;
                case "btnUpdate5":
                    dt = Convert.ToDateTime(_obj.Dates.Now5.ToString());
                    break;
                case "btnUpdate6":
                    dt = Convert.ToDateTime(_obj.Dates.Now6.ToString());
                    break;
                case "btnUpdate7":
                    dt = Convert.ToDateTime(_obj.Dates.Now7.ToString());
                    break;
                case "btnUpdate8":
                    dt = Convert.ToDateTime(_obj.Dates.Now8.ToString());
                    break;
                case "btnUpdate9":
                    dt = Convert.ToDateTime(_obj.Dates.Now9.ToString());
                    break;
                case "btnUpdate10":
                    dt = Convert.ToDateTime(_obj.Dates.Now10.ToString());
                    break;
                case "btnUpdate11":
                    dt = Convert.ToDateTime(_obj.Dates.Now11.ToString());
                    break;
                case "btnUpdate12":
                    dt = Convert.ToDateTime(_obj.Dates.Now12.ToString());
                    break;
                case "btnUpdate13":
                    dt = Convert.ToDateTime(_obj.Dates.Now13.ToString());
                    break;
                case "btnUpdate14":
                    dt = Convert.ToDateTime(_obj.Dates.Now14.ToString());
                    break;
                case "btnUpdate15":
                    dt = Convert.ToDateTime(_obj.Dates.Now15.ToString());
                    break;
                case "btnUpdate16":
                    dt = Convert.ToDateTime(_obj.Dates.Now16.ToString());
                    break;
                case "btnUpdate17":
                    dt = Convert.ToDateTime(_obj.Dates.Now17.ToString());
                    break;
                case "btnUpdate18":
                    dt = Convert.ToDateTime(_obj.Dates.Now18.ToString());
                    break;
                case "btnUpdate19":
                    dt = Convert.ToDateTime(_obj.Dates.Now19.ToString());
                    break;
                case "btnUpdate20":
                    dt = Convert.ToDateTime(_obj.Dates.Now20.ToString());
                    break;
                case "btnUpdate21":
                    dt = Convert.ToDateTime(_obj.Dates.Now21.ToString());
                    break;
                case "btnUpdate22":
                    dt = Convert.ToDateTime(_obj.Dates.Now22.ToString());
                    break;
                case "btnUpdate23":
                    dt = Convert.ToDateTime(_obj.Dates.Now23.ToString());
                    break;
                case "btnUpdate24":
                    dt = Convert.ToDateTime(_obj.Dates.Now24.ToString());
                    break;
                case "btnUpdate25":
                    dt = Convert.ToDateTime(_obj.Dates.Now25.ToString());
                    break;
                case "btnUpdate26":
                    dt = Convert.ToDateTime(_obj.Dates.Now26.ToString());
                    break;
                case "btnUpdate27":
                    dt = Convert.ToDateTime(_obj.Dates.Now27.ToString());
                    break;
                case "btnUpdate28":
                    dt = Convert.ToDateTime(_obj.Dates.Now28.ToString());
                    break;
                case "btnUpdate29":
                    dt = Convert.ToDateTime(_obj.Dates.Now29.ToString());
                    break;
                case "btnUpdate30":
                    dt = Convert.ToDateTime(_obj.Dates.Now30.ToString());
                    break;

            }

            System.Windows.MessageBox.Show(dt.ToString("ddd"));
        }
```

Can somebody suggest me better approach for this one I believe we need to customize existing calendar

Comment: You can add this properties dynamically at least

Comment: How i can do that plz tell me

Comment: Anyone else getting that 'homework' vibe?

Answer (score 1):

I would probably display an ItemsControl whose ItemsSource is a List of DateTime and make a DataTemplate on DateTime to display a button.

XAML:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding ListOfDates, Mode=OneWay}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type DateTime}">
            <Button Click="ClickHandler">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding StringFormat={}{0:D}}"/>
            </Button>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
</ItemsControl>
```

back cs:

```
public void ClickHandler(Object sender, MouseEventArgs args) {
    DateTime correspondingDate = (DateTime)((Button)sender).DataContext;
    MessageBox.Show(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.GetDayName(correspondingDate.DayOfWeek));
}
```

ViewModel:

```
public class YourVM {
    public YourVM() {
        int startYear = DateTime.Now.Year;
        DateTime currentDate = new DateTime(startYear, 1, 1);
        while(currentDate.Year == startYear) {
            _listOfDates.Add(currentDate);
            currentDate = currentDate.AddDays(1);
        }
    }

    private List<DateTime> _listOfDates = new List<DateTime>(365);
    public List<DateTime> ListOfDates { get { return _listOfDates; } }
}
```

Comment: Tell me button creation logic?

Comment: We tell WPF to display DateTimes as Buttons. As the ItemsControl contains DateTime it'll create as many Button as DateTime in the ItemsSource.

Comment: If i am using command ,why do we need to write conveter <Button CommandParameter="{Binding}"  >
                        <Button.Command>
                            <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource LabelMultiValueConverter}">
                                <Binding Path="DataContext.UpdateCommand"
                                     ElementName="CommentsList" />
                                <Binding />
                            </MultiBinding>
                        </Button.Command>

Comment: Suppose i am implementing MVVM and Icommand is implementing inpace of handler

Comment: Event handlers and commands have two different purposes. Event handlers are in the View layer whereas commands are in the ViewModel layer. You want to display something when you click on a Button: In my opinion this is something that should be in the View layer. But if you want to do it in the ViewModel all you have to do is : CommandParameter="{Binding}" Command="{Binding YourCommand, Mode=OneWay}" And in your Command function call: MessageBox.Show(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.GetDayName(((DateTime)parameter).DayOfWeek));

Comment: Thanks.To Bind Command we need to create like this Button CommandParameter="{Binding}"  Template="{StaticResource ButtonTemplate}" >
                        <Button.Command>
                            <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource LabelMultiValueConverter}">
                                <Binding Path="DataContext.UpdateCommand"
                                     ElementName="CommentsList" />
                                <Binding />
                            </MultiBinding>
                           </Button.Command>

Comment: @Sudhir.net You don't need a converter to use ICommand, please read this [article](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/813345/Basic-MVVM-and-ICommand-Usage-Example)

Comment: @ nkoniishvt-Please provide me the link